# COMO IMPLEMENTAR ESSA ABA FIXA ENTRE AS ACTIVITIES?

Tags: android, layout

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto Android, tipo uma rede social, estou com a idéia, ela é boa, mas eu estou querendo implementar uma função: 
Um menu fixo, tipo, no aplicativo do facebook, tem um menu fixo, de Feed de Notícias, notificações, e solicitações de amizade.
Mas eu quero colocar os meus:
Um feed, um campo de galeria, entre outros, mas eu não sei criar essa aba de menu fixo, é só ela mesmo, eu sei fazer as animações de boa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisará usar tabs, olhe o exemplo abaixo:

No build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

Na sua MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new 
 ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    //Esses 3 fragments ainda iremos criar
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

Seu xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Então você cria seus fragments, nesse exemplo usarei 3 abas, vou colocar o código de apenas uma:

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragmentText)).setText("One");

    return view;
}
```

}

Xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="danielrocha.androidtabs.OneFragment">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentText"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Repita o código para os outros dois fragments, e mude o nome da classe, claro.

Esse será o resultado:

https://rochadaniel.github.io/static/img/posts/tabs/tabs1.png

Para colocar icones vc coloca esse método aba na MainActivity:

```
private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.seuicone);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.seuicone);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.seuicone);
}
```

Para que as tabs tenham apenas icones, dentro do ViewPagerAdapter você modifica o método getPageTitle(), o faço retornar nulo:

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

// returno nulo
return null;
}
```

Acho que é isso.
Fonte: https://rochadaniel.github.io/android/2016/09/22/Android-Trabalhando-com-Tabs.html

Comment: Valeu amigo, agora eu vou estudar por cima do código, ralar pra entender rsrsrs, muito obrigado mesmo

Comment: @JirenSama se conseguir aí e quiser marcar minha resposta como aceita eu agradeço kkkk

Comment: Como se faz isso, sou novo nesse site rsrsrs

Comment: @JirenSama Abaixo do botão de avaliar negativamente, ele é tipo um V

Comment: Achei rsrsrssrsr

Comment: @JirenSama obrigado, tenha uma ótima noite

Comment: posso fazer só mais uma pergunta ? Como tu conseguiu construir esses códigos, tu domina, da muito trabalho ? tu se tornou especialista como ? me uma dica rsrsrs

Comment: @JirenSama cara, esse aí eu peguei um exemplo do link meio q pronto e adicionei, não sou especialista mas domino bem, pra aprender só na prática mesmo, você tem que ir fazendo seus projetos, achando problemas e resolvendo, aí você vai amadurecendo e aprendendo com seus erros. Você também pode fazer um curso, recomendo procurar na udemy.com, lá você acha cursos bem baratos

Comment: vlw, irei fazer isso